# Array formula in EPPLUS

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I'm trying to generate an excel file with EPPlus that contains a formula summing elements if a condition is met. If read the documentation correctly, last versions (I'm using EPPlus 4.0.5 installed by Nuget) should support such formulas.

Here is a short example

```
var pck = new ExcelPackage (fileinfo);
var sheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add ("My sheet");

sheet.Cells [1, 1, 1, 5].Value = 1;
sheet.Cells [1, 6, 1, 10].Value = 0;

sheet.Cells [2, 1, 2, 10].Value = 1;

//sheet.Cells [3, 1].Value = "=SUM(IF(A1:J1>0;A2:J2))";
sheet.Cells [3, 1].CreateArrayFormula ("SUM(IF(A1:J1>0;A2:J2))");

pck.Save ();
pck.Dispose ();
```

When I open the file with Excel, Excel ask for repairing the file (and just empty the cell containing the array formula).

If I only set the value and execute the formula as array formula in Excel, everything works fine (so formula is not the culprit).

Any idea of what is wrong? Or any idea on how to workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Formula is the culprit. Never that anything for granted.

It appears that input format and format used internally in the file are different.

```
sheet.Cells [3, 1].CreateArrayFormula ("SUM(IF(A1:J1>0;A2:J2))");
```

does not work but

```
sheet.Cells [3, 1].CreateArrayFormula ("SUM(IF(A1:J1>0,A2:J2))");
```

(Note the comma vs. semi-colon)

On my computer, I need to encode the formula with a semi-colon, not a comma.

Comment: This might be caused by a different local used by excel. French local use ";" and I think engligh local use ","

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
sheet.Cells [3, 1].CreateArrayFormula ("IF(SUM(A1:J1)>0,SUM(A2:J2))");
```